# Output from Eclipse CDT on Linux have incorrect permission

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm having problems with files created from within Eclipse running on Linux.
All files (as far as I know) only gets the owner read and write permissions. Build output is the same but with the execute permission added.

The "test" file is created in Eclipse by File > New, and the "test1" file is created in command line by "touch" by the same user in the same folder.

```
-rw-------. 1 user stdgroup     0 Mar 15 10:22 test
-rw-r--r--. 1 user stdgroup     0 Mar 15 10:23 test1
```

My umask is set to 0022, so the output from the "touched" file is correct.

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2 on Linux RedHatEnterpriseServer 7.3.

Anyone knows if there is a setting in Eclipse that can cause this, or any other ideas as to why this happens?